# Sensu send alerts only to concerned team for notifications

Tags: json, monitoring, sensu

Am using sensu server with Elastic cache and have a huge list of clients that they are tiring to send a message but during the keepalive or any notification am using handlers using SNS topic.

But I have differentiated the client but adding Subscriber so that i can identify what is prod and non-prod but notification am not able to split with diff SNS topics using multiple handlers.

Comment: can you show your mailer configuration?

Comment: {
"handlers":{
"default":{
"command":"handler-sns.rb",
"severities":["critical"],
"type":"pipe"
},
"sns":{
"command":"handler-sns.rb",
"severities":["critical"],
"type":"pipe"
}
},
"sns":{
"topic_arn":"arn:aws:sns:us-eas:Sensu-Prod",
"use_ami_role":true
}
}